# Error: a class qualified name is not allowed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, using-declaration

I'm getting an error at line `using std::list<int>::iterator`.
The compiler gives the error
`Error: a class-qualified name is not allowed.`

I am unsure what is the problem? Can someone expand on the compilers problem with my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::list;
using std::list<int>::iterator;

int main( )
{
    list<int> listObject;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        listObject.push_back(i);
    cout << "List contains:\n";

    iterator iter;
    for (iter = listObject.begin( ); iter != listObject.end( ); iter++)
        cout << *iter << " ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Setting all entries to 0:\n";
    for (iter = listObject.begin( ); iter != listObject.end( ); iter++)
        *iter = 0;
    cout << "List now contains:\n";
    
    for (iter = listObject.begin( ); iter != listObject.end( ); iter++)
        cout << *iter << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally, when tasking a question about an error, it's very helpful to post the error text

Answer (score 10):

You can't bring a name from the class scope into namespace scope with `using` directive. You can only be `using` a name defined at namespace scope, in a different namespace.

Comment: You either spell out `list<int>::iterator` as needed, or you `typedef` it.